# laravel newly created author class not working

Tags: php, laravel

ReflectionException (-1)

Class authors does not exist Open: C:\wamp\www\laravel-4.2.11\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php

I am facing the above error when I run this. Can any one help on this?

Comment: add some code to your question, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try running `composer dump`

Answer (score 2):

Open a console, `cd` to `C:\wamp\www\laravel-4.2.11\`, then run the command `composer dump-autoload`.

Note: you may need to use a full path to composer if it is not in your `$PATH`, for example `"C:\Program Files\composer dump-autoload"`. Also, don't forget to quote strings which might have spaces in them.

You can spare yourself all this trouble if you use `artisan` to generate Models and Controllers, AFAIK it runs the `dump-autoload` automatically for you. If you're running Laravel 4.2, you can include this package in your project:
[Laravel 4 Generators](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators)